# Exponential maths operator

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, numerical-algorithms

I have written a math library which handles really big numbers with good precision. Each digit is stored in a nibble and a 'nibble array' makes up the number. There is no epsilon portion, as for currency calculation big brother is happy enough to loose penny fractions with int like rounding.

My problem is $a^b$ . It's all ok if $b$ is an integer value, but what if it has decimal digits.

But how to calculate $4.613765^{3.14259}$ from first principles. It's so long since I did a-level math I don't know where to begin.

> How to calculate $a^b$ when $b$ is not an integer?

Comment: Since both are rational numbers, you can write them on the form of $\frac{a}{b}^{\frac{n}{m}} = (\sqrt[m]{\frac{a}{b}})^n$.  Or in your case, if you'd like to compute $4.6^{22/7}$, you can rewrite to $(\sqrt[7]{4.6})^{22}$.  Of course, I don't really know how to compute $\sqrt[7]{4.6}$ exactly, so I'm not sure this is in the right direction ...

Comment: @PålGD I can do sqrt by liner interpolation. What do operators prefix\ and a number in set brackets{ }. I'm guessing fraction is the digits after the decimal point. What's $ about

Comment: @rhubarbdog That's LaTeX; if you enable scripts here (and other SE sites), in particular those from mathjax.org, you'll see rendered mathematics. (Of course, the Android app can't do it; better use a browser for math-heavy SE sites.)

Comment: @PålGD's comment without the mathematical mark-up is: "Since both are rational numbers, you can write them in the form of (a/b)^(n/m) = (mth root of a/b)^n. Or in your case, if you'd like to compute 4.6^(22/7), you can rewrite to (7th root of 4.6)^22. Of course, I don't really know how to compute the seventh root of 4.6 exactly so I'm not sure this is in the right direction."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I may have thrown a curved ball here. I want this to work for any a and any b. I should not have used a pi approximation as on of the terms, as for the other number (a) sorry if that also has 'magic' properties.

Comment: @rhubarbdog I'm not aware of any magic properties of pi in this respect. But the point is that your numbers are rational by construction because your library stores a number as a list of decimal digits. Every number you can represent has the form a/b or, more specifically, a/(10^c).

Comment: @DavidRicherby does this imply I express the exponent as an integer / 10^x . Where x is the multiplier to make my decimal have no fractional part. If this is the case I imagine root to the 10^ x is going to be expensive to calculate. Any other methods?

Comment: I would guess the usual implementation calculates $x^y = \exp (y\log x)$, reducing the problem to the computation of $\exp$ and $\log$, which is another matter altogether. But why would you implement your own bignum library? Use GMP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what's GMP. Tried Google got no good links. I wrote library to handle sums of cash, I have + - which run ok * % / which are slower.  The need for ^ only came about when I was going to publish this 0.0.0 beta version to allow a poster on stack overflow continue his quest for big ints .

Comment: That's the GNU Multiprecission library, which already implements everything having to do with big ints and even arbitrary precision floating point numbers. No need to reimplement these things.

Comment: Didn't know it existed. I knowing was a unlicensed challenge implementing + - ,  * a bit tricky and  needed speeding up.  % / are a bit brute force. I didn't want a bigger more precise double, I need it to be an int with decimal places. This maintains a known rounding loss which inland revenue,  the vat man etc tollerate

Comment: @YuvalFilmus before I give up what base is the log to and what does the exp function do.

Comment: You can choose whatever base you want for the logarithm, as long as you use the same base for the exponent. Usually one chooses base $e$ for both.